# "smart" android activation from a push notification

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, push-notification, back-stack

I have a simple task - activate an app from the push on a particular activity (not on the start activity)

Imaging I have 3 activities in the app:

1. A (splash)
2. B (items list)
3. C (selected item details)

Some pre-requirements:

- With push I'm getting the id of item to select.
- On the splash I'm forcing an authentication.
- One of the conditions - I couldn't move authentication let's say to another activity or to application service for example.

Now I could create several statements. When I tap on push to activate the app:

1. When push is arrived the PushIntentService generates a notification which specifies item id in intent extras If the app was terminated I should start the app from the activity A (to force authentication)
2. If the app was backgrounded (works in background) I should re-activate it at the same place (to skip re-authentication)
3. Once the app is activate I will navigate to Activity C with item id fetched from extras.

Right now I'm using the following code to generate the notification (item 1, Xamarin.Android syntax):

```
var resultIntent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(SplashScreen));
resultIntent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop); 
if (extras.ContainsKey("ItemId"))
{
    var itemId = extras["ItemId"];
    resultIntent.PutExtra("ItemId", itemId);
}
var resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(Application.Context, 0, resultIntent, 0);
builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
var notification = builder.Build();
```

This notification works absolutely fine in all cases but I see here one issue.
I'm restarting the app from the very beginning every time I'm tapping on a notification.
What I want is when the app is backgrounded I need just to activate it (like iOS does) and navigate to required page (faster activation and avoid re-authentication).

How can I achieve this and modify the code above?

Comment: as per my thinking you need to use flag for that i mean when your app is opened then make it true when app is closed make it false and keep that flag in shared preferrences so when you receive notification just check what is the value of flag if its true then skip the step if false then proceed for authentication its very simple logic hope it will work for you

Comment: unfortunately I have to make a decision without checking whether app is running. Because it could be opened when we generating that notification and it could be closed after we generated and before we opened the app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on how to simulate launcher icon tap intent. I'm using it to create pending intent for my push:

`var launchIntent = PackageManager.GetLaunchIntentForPackage(PackageName);`

This is exactly what I wanted and it works perfectly fine in my case.

Comment: But this will not deliver any extras (like your "id") from the notification to the app if the app was already running. It will just bring the app to the foreground in whatever state it was in when it went to the background. Is that what you wanted? Your question seemed to indicate that you wanted something else.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Activity` for this. The notification should start that `Activity` (without any flags).
In `onCreate()` of this new `Activity`, do something like this:

```
super.onCreate(...);
if (!isTaskRoot() && alreadyAuthenticated) {
    // Go directly to details page
    Intent redirectIntent = new Intent(this, Details.class)
    redirect.putExtra("id", itemId);
    startActivity(redirectIntent);
else {
    // This means the app was not running, so redirect to Splash
    Intent redirectIntent = new Intent(this, Splash.class)
    startActivity(redirectIntent);
}
finish();
```

`isTaskRoot()` will return `true` if the app was not running when the user clicked on the `Notification`. If the app was already running, it should return `false`.

To test if you are already authenticated, you could call a `static` method or check a `static` variable or maybe you have some other method of doing this. Depending on what you want the `Activity` stack to look like if the user was already in the "item details" or "item list" activites, you may want to add `SINGLE_TOP` and/or `CLEAR_TOP` flags when redirecting to the item details `Activity`.

Hopefully you get the point.